# Add 2 links in between the navigation using the Breadcrumb Navxt plugin hook

Tags: plugins, php, functions, hooks, actions

**I am using the Breadcrumb NavXT Plugin.**

I have 2 links at a page, and want to add 2 more links in between on that specific page.

I used the below hook, but did not get the result.

```
add_filter('bcn_breadcrumb_title', 'my_breadcrumb_title', 3, 10);

function my_breadcrumb_title($title, $type, $id)
{
    if(in_array('post-page', $type) && get_post_meta($id, 'last_breadcrumb_title', true)) {
        $title = get_post_meta($id, 'last_breadcrumb_title', true)
    }

    return $title;
}
```